# Matrix multiplication with scattered NA values

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication, na

I'm looking to multiply two matrices together in R, one of which may contain randomly placed NA values (i.e., there's no reason they will be all in a row or column), but I still want an output like the example below:

```
Matrix 1
[1,]      33        45    50
[2,]       NA       NA    54

Matrix 2
[1,] A1               0.0000000        0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000        A2               0.0000000
[3,] 0.0000000        0.0000000           A3


Result
[1,]      33*A1     45*A2          50*A3
[2,]       NA       NA        (NA*0 +NA*0 +54*A3)=54*A3
```

Simply doing Matrix1%*%Matrix2 doesn't give what I want for the element in Row 2, Column 3 (it gives NA, which makes sense, but not sure how to do what I'd like it to do).  For my purposes, Matrix 2 will never have NA values, if that changes anything.

Comment: I was expecting to find an `inner` function to match R's `outer` function, allowing you to write your own custom operation like this. Oh well, it looks like it does not exist. I wonder why.

Answer (score 13):

Change all occurrences of `NA` to 0, then do the matrix multiplication:

```
x <- matrix(c(33, 45, 50, NA, NA, 54), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
y <- diag(1:3)


x[is.na(x)] <- 0

x %*% y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   33   90  150
[2,]    0    0  162
```

Comment: The only trick would be converting those 2 0's in the result to NA's. In my case, the distinction is that exp(0)=1, whereas exp(NA)=NA. When operating on a log scale, I use NA to represent "nothing".

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the previous answer and its comment: you can apply the NA pattern of the input matrix into the output matrix.

This works only if input and output matrices are of the same dimension.

```
x <- matrix(c(33, 45, 50, NA, NA, 54), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
y <- diag(1:3)

x0 <- x
x0[is.na(x)] <- 0

z <- x0 %*% y

z[is.na(x)] <- NA

z
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   33   90  150
[2,]   NA   NA  162
```