# Rolling weighted sum across table with NA in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to get rolling weighted sums across a table, and have a method involving matrix multiplication, but it breaks when some of the data is missing.

So if I use

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- tibble(Country = c("Australia", "Canada"),
                 "1980" = c(1000, 2000),
                 "1981" = c(1100, 2100),
                 "1982" = c(1300, 2300),
                 "1983" = c(1200, 2400),
                 "1984" = c(1400, 2200),
                 "1985" = c(1500, 2500))
weights <- c(3, 4, 6)

n0 <- ncol(mydata) - length(weights)
matweights <- matrix(rep(c(rep(0, n0), weights), n0)[-(1:n0)], ncol=n0) 
tibble(cbind(mydata[, 1], as.matrix(mydata[, -1]) %*%  matweights))
```

I get what I want with

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Country     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Australia 15200 15700 17100 18200
2 Canada    28200 29900 29700 31000
```

where for example in the top right `18200` is `3*1200 + 4*1400 + 6*1500`

But if for example one of the values is missing, say `mydata[2, 3] <- NA` then I would get

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Country     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Australia 15200 15700 17100 18200
2 Canada       NA    NA    NA    NA
```

when I want

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Country     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Australia 15200 15700 17100 18200
2 Canada       NA    NA 29700 31000
```

The problem with my matrix approach is `0 * NA` giving `NA` when I want it to be `0`.  I know there are solutions using some kind of *apply* approach but I suspect that may be slower with a large table.

Comment: It seems like this addresses what you want, matrix multiplication with NA handling:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535084/matrix-multiplication-with-scattered-na-values

Comment: @Baroque That is a nice idea (turning NA to 0s, doing the multiplication and than turning 0s into NAs).  In my real case, 0s are possible, though unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really quite like [slider](https://davisvaughan.github.io/slider/) for sliding functions—it's very flexible, and has a purrr-like syntax. Here, `slide_index_dbl()` will let us slide a function and use another variable as an index by which to decide what observations are within the window.

First, reshape to long form and group, then it's a single call within `mutate()`. `.before` here specifies how many years back to include; `.complete` specifies to ignore partial windows.

```r
library(tidyverse)

out1 <- mydata %>% 
    gather(year, value, -Country, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    mutate(
        value_3y = slider::slide_index_dbl(
            value, .i = year, 
            .f = ~sum(.x * weights), 
            .before = 2, .complete = TRUE
        )
    )

out1
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>    Country    year value value_3y
#>    <chr>     <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Australia  1980  1000       NA
#>  2 Canada     1980  2000       NA
#>  3 Australia  1981  1100       NA
#>  4 Canada     1981  2100       NA
#>  5 Australia  1982  1300    15200
#>  6 Canada     1982  2300    28200
#>  7 Australia  1983  1200    15700
#>  8 Canada     1983  2400    29900
#>  9 Australia  1984  1400    17100
#> 10 Canada     1984  2200    29700
#> 11 Australia  1985  1500    18200
#> 12 Canada     1985  2500    31000
```

To reshape to wide form:

```r
out1 %>% 
    select(-value) %>%
    drop_na() %>%    # omit to keep partial/empty years
    spread(year, value_3y)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>   Country   `1982` `1983` `1984` `1985`
#>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Australia  15200  15700  17100  18200
#> 2 Canada     28200  29900  29700  31000
```

If the data contains `NA`s, the code works exactly the same:

```r
mydata[2, 3] <- NA

out2 <- mydata %>% 
    gather(year, value, -Country, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    mutate(
        value_3y = slider::slide_index_dbl(
            value, .i = year, 
            .f = ~sum(.x * weights), 
            .before = 2, .complete = TRUE
        )
    )

out2
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>    Country    year value value_3y
#>    <chr>     <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Australia  1980  1000       NA
#>  2 Canada     1980  2000       NA
#>  3 Australia  1981  1100       NA
#>  4 Canada     1981    NA       NA
#>  5 Australia  1982  1300    15200
#>  6 Canada     1982  2300       NA
#>  7 Australia  1983  1200    15700
#>  8 Canada     1983  2400       NA
#>  9 Australia  1984  1400    17100
#> 10 Canada     1984  2200    29700
#> 11 Australia  1985  1500    18200
#> 12 Canada     1985  2500    31000

out2 %>% 
    select(-value) %>%
    drop_na() %>% 
    spread(year, value_3y)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>   Country   `1982` `1983` `1984` `1985`
#>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Australia  15200  15700  17100  18200
#> 2 Canada        NA     NA  29700  31000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using rollapply we have the following matrix:

```
library(zoo)
t(rollapply(t(mydata[, -1]), 3, function(x) sum(x * weights)))
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
## [1,] 15200 15700 17100 18200
## [2,]    NA    NA 29700 31000
```

Answer (score 1):

Linear `filter`ing option:

```
t(apply(mydata[-1], 1, stats::filter, filter=rev(weights), sides=1))
#     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#[1,]   NA   NA 15200 15700 17100 18200
#[2,]   NA   NA    NA    NA 29700 31000
```